Installing one version of jinja2 module but Jupyter notebook shows a different one
I am trying to run Llama 3.1 8b model through huggingface. After completing all the steps I got this error
ImportError: apply_chat_template requires jinja2>=3.1.0 to be installed. Your version is 3.0.3.```

The reason for this error being that my device has jinja2 version 3.0.3. So to rectify this I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the latest version using the code below (Note: All code is in the same cell) :
print("---------- Uninstalling ----------\n\n")
!python -m pip uninstall jinja2 --yes

print("---------- Installing ----------\n\n")

!pip install jinja2 -U

print("---------- Checking Version ----------\n\n")

import jinja2
print("This current jinja2 version is :" + str(jinja2.__version__))

Although the code above installs the latest verison, when I print it, it still shows the older verison (see output snipped below).
---------- Uninstalling ----------


Found existing installation: Jinja2 3.1.4
Uninstalling Jinja2-3.1.4:
  Successfully uninstalled Jinja2-3.1.4
---------- Installing ----------


Collecting jinja2
  Using cached jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\sahil\desktop\projects\llama_env\lib\site-packages (from jinja2) (2.1.5)
Using cached jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Installing collected packages: jinja2
Successfully installed jinja2-3.1.4
---------- Checking Version ----------


This current jinja2 version is :3.0.3

I tried restarting the kernel but that did not work. How can I fix this issue?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

You seem to have the stable release installed and you are not specifying the version of Jinja2 to uninstall.
To uninstall Jinja2 3.0.3, specify the version:
!pip uninstall Jinja2==3.0.3 --yes


Please don't suggest outdated use of an exclamation point in conjunction with pip use in a notebook cell. It should be the magic symbol %pip ... in modern Jupyter now as it was added in 2019 to overcome the issues the exclamation point can cause. Namely, the magic version of the command ensures the action occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. The exclamation point doesn't do that and was often leading to issues. Please see here for more about this with links to resources therein.
